# Long list of attributes that make typical graph labels

Tags: data-request, data.gov, api

Sort of similar to the fantastic "[Spurious Correlations](http://tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations)" page, I'm looking for long lists of typical **x** or **y** axis labels from graphs (as keys, attributes or column names). For example (and see image below):

- Per capita cheese consumption
- Number of people who died by becoming tangled in their bedsheets

I'd prefer as many diverse themes, topics and categories as possible. Data can be collected live from an API, or from a scraped site or parsed file (any format).

---

One way may be to use the [API from data.gov](https://www.data.gov/developers/apis) - does anyone know how I can get column names from files or DB exports using this or another CKAN API?

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that most of the data on data.gov is not actually in CKAN's datastore -- it's just linked in a catalog-like fashion and so there isn't a way to get the columns.